# iMacros set Value in a special Dropdown

Tags: imacros, dropdown

have a small Problem to choose a value ID in special Dropdown Box with iMacros. The Dropdown is on mrssporty.de/. It's the first Box in the main Fomular for Selecting the Club.

I have the the Value Ids like this:

```
<select id="clubUid" name="form66[clubUid]" class="form-control select select2 select2init">
    <option value="">PLZ oder Ort eingeben *</option>

        <option value="1139" >Aalen (73430, Bahnhofstraße 8)</option>

        <option value="26" >Ahrensburg (22926, Grosse Strasse 2)</option>

        <option value="27" >Aichach (86551, Augsburgerstr. 17)</option>

        <option value="1128" >Altötting (84503, Marienstr.3)</option>

        <option value="29" >Alzey (55232, Berliner Strasse 3)</option>
```

and want to choose one value above with iMacros like

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=* ATTR=ID:select2-drop CONTENT=$1139
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these settings in Recording Options.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uurJ.png

And record selection of drop down.

If you have multiple dropdowns and u want to do them all you can record 2 or 3. Then you can see which number inside () is changing. Then place !LOOP inside that number.

(!LOOP)

With little work u will see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks. I Tried it and know what you mean. I can see the diferent selectors. But these are not the <option value = "29" IDs. So, i have a CSV with the option value Numbers and want to select with them the Dropdown.

Comment: IF it works the good. If not then expalin so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

actually i solved it like that

```
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR="#select2-chosen-3" BUTTON=0 
CLICK X=646 Y=267
wait seconds=1
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#s2id_autogen3_search" CHARS="12587"
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#s2id_autogen3_search" KEYS="[13,13]"
```

But its not really smart. Anyone a better Idea?